# changing progress bar as scrolling

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, progress-bar, scrollview, android-progressbar

I'm making a project in Kotlin that has a view with a long text inside a recyclerView. I wanted to put a linear progress bar to show how much text is left.

Currently I have this:

```
 binding.rvBody.setOnScrollChangeListener { _, _, _, _, oldScrollY ->
            // se computa el valor absoluto (queremos que total sea positivo)
            val total = binding.rvBody.height

            binding.progressBar?.apply {
                max = total
                progress += -oldScrollY
            }
            // si está arriba, el valor será 0
            if (!binding.rvBody.canScrollVertically(-1)) { // si no se puede hacer scroll hacia arriba
                binding.progressBar?.setProgressCompat(0, true)
            }
            // si está abajo, el valor será el total
            if (!binding.rvBody.canScrollVertically(1)) { // si no se puede hacer scroll hacia abajo
                binding.progressBar?.setProgressCompat(total, true)
            }
        }
```

The progressBar right now is moving as scrolling, but it gets to the end of the bar before getting to the end of the text, and it goes back to the begining of the bar also before getting to the begining again.

Comment: You said you're using a `ScrollView` but your code is working with a `RecyclerView`. Do you have a `RecyclerView` *inside* a `ScrollView`? That's a bad sign, and it might just be that your RV isn't scrolling at all, because it's big enough to display all its items at once (which is how you're meant to handle your content inside a `ScrollView`). You might want to post your XML for the layout too

Comment: I don't. I have a recyclerView, I just wrote the wrong word

Answer (score 0):

I had the same functionality working,
I have a scroll view instead of a recycler view.

scroll is the id of ScrollView
and progress is the ProgressBar

```
binding.scroll.setOnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->

val totalScrollHeight = binding.scroll.getChildAt(0).height - binding.scroll.height

binding.progressBar.apply{

max=totalScrollHeight
progress=scrollY

}
}
```

This code is working perfectly hope it works at your end too :)

Comment: It might be because I have a RecyclerView, but it is not working :( Also I cannot change it to a ScrollView because of all the things inside of it.

Comment: @SalmandraReader then add your xml , so I can test it properly

Answer (score 0):

`verticalScrollbarPosition` [doesn't do what you think it does](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getVerticalScrollbarPosition()).

> `public int getVerticalScrollbarPosition ()`
>
> Returns
> `int`  The position where the vertical scroll bar will show, if applicable.

To make it clearer what it's actually returning, let's look at [`setVerticalScrollbarPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setVerticalScrollbarPosition(int)):

> `public void setVerticalScrollbarPosition (int position)`
>
> Set the position of the vertical scroll bar. Should be one of `SCROLLBAR_POSITION_DEFAULT`, `SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT` or `SCROLLBAR_POSITION_RIGHT`.

So `verticalScrollbarPosition` doesn't give you *the position of the scrollable thumb as a percentage of the scrollbar's height*, it just gives you *a fixed constant that says where the scrollbar is drawn*. So it's not what you're looking for, and never changes anyway.

---

I don't have time to experiment with this, but you probably want to use [`computeVerticalScrollOffset`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ScrollingView#computeVerticalScrollOffset()) and [`computeVerticalScrollRange`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ScrollingView#computeVerticalScrollRange()) on the `RecyclerView` (which is inheriting those methods from its `ScrollingView` supertype) and calculate `offset / range.toFloat()`. It says the units are arbitrary, but consistent between the two, so that should give you the correct percentage (you need to convert to floating point so you don't just get `0` or `1` by dividing two ints)

Also you should be using `addOnScrollListener` really, `seOnScrollChangeListener` is deprecated!